# How to update data using real-time (SignalR)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I am writing to seek help, in regards creating a real-time data update using SignalR. I am currently having issue on the client-side, where I am unable to render the data content.

I have a tested the query command and it seems to be returning data.  This leads me to believe, that my client-side code, maybe incorrect.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.          
    var notifications = $.connection.NotificationHub;
    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    notifications.client.recieveNotification = function (role, descrip) {
        // Add the message to the page.                    
        $('#spanNewMessages').text(role);
        $('#spanNewCircles').text(descrip);

    };
    // Start the connection.
   $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        notifications.server.sendNotifications(function () {
            alert("does it work");
            });
    }).fail(function (e) {
        alert(e);
    });
 </script>
 <h1>New Notifications</h1>
 <div>
<b>New <span id="spanNewMessages"></span> role.</b><br />
<b>New<span id="spanNewCircles"></span> descrip.</b><br />

 </div>
```

Hub Class:

```
  [HubName("NotificationHub")]
  public class notificationHub : Hub
  {
    string role = "";
    string descrip = "";

    [HubMethodName("sendNotifications")]
    public void SendNotifications()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dummyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT [role],[description] FROM [dbo].[User]";
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {                  
                command.Notification = null;                
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();                
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(reader);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    role = dt.Rows[0]["role"].ToString();
                    descrip = dt.Rows[0]["description"].ToString();

                }
            }  
        }

     Clients.All.RecieveNotification(role, descrip);
    }
    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            notificationHub nHub = new notificationHub();
            nHub.SendNotifications();
        }
    }

}
```

StartUp CLass:

```
 using Microsoft.Owin;
 using Owin;
 using WebApplication2;

 namespace WebApplication2
 {
   public class Startup
    {
       public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
       {
        app.MapSignalR();
       }
    }
  }
```

Could anyone, please provide some assistant, to where I may be going wrong with this task. Thank you.

Comment: you should probably post your Hub code too.  Is the hub's `SendNotifications` getting called?  Is the hub's `OnConnected` getting called?

Comment: @Jonesy, Thank you for your reply. I have updated my code with the Hub class, for further reference.  Any feedback would be most welcomed. Thanks

Comment: when you load up your page, is `SendNotifications` getting called?

Comment: @Jonesy, apology for the late response.  Sorry, I am slightly new into understanding SignalR, but how can I test, if the `SendNotifications ` method is being called. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mocked up your app.  Your issue was you are returning a string from your hub action:

```
public string SendNotifications()
{
    return context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(role, descrip);
}
```

this should be void (you aren't returning anything, but actually calling the clients), and you also don't need to use GlobalHost to get the context here, only when the context isn't available (I.E. calling the hub from the server).  Try making these changes:

```
[HubMethodName("sendNotifications")]
public void SendNotifications()
{
    //using...

    //IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<notificationHub>();
    //return context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(role, descrip);

    Clients.All.RecieveNotification(role, descrip);
}
```

Put a breakpoint at `Clients.All...` and see if it is being triggered.  Let me know if these updates fix your issue.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your help and time into this.  I am sorry to inform, that I was unable to fix the issue, by following you above suggestion.  I have updated my code, as shown in the question above to your suggestion.  I could not get the breakpoint to work on the `Client.All` code. I tried adding a alert box in `SendNotifications` Jquery and that does not seems to work either.  My Jquery code is in `index.aspx` and my notification code in my a separate `hub` class, maybe I need to bind these together? Please advice further, if possible.

Comment: in your startup class did you map your signalr?  If you browse to `yoursite/signalr/hubs` you should see a javascript file if SignalR is set up correctly.  Whoops, you need to also change this `<script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript" ></script>` to `<script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript" ></script>`

Comment: Dear @Jonesy, Thank you for your reply back.  I again made the changes as required but I am not still not getting any content shown on the client-side.  I tested it using `http://localhost:4876/Real-Time/Index.aspx/signalr/hubs`, but I am still getting the same problem.  I could not find much on startUP class for the SignalR.  Is there anything else I need to add to that class, if I am missing something from there.  Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to help.  I'd recommend running through a tutorial [like this one](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5) and getting the feel of it.  It's likely some small syntactical error we're overlooking.

Comment: Dear @Jonesy, Many thanks for your time and help into this.  I appreciate your support and hardwork. Thank you.